# テーブルの操作をjavascriptでしたい。

Tags: javascript

1のチェックボックスをクリックするとサンプル1だけ表示され、サンプル2とサンプル3は表示されないようにしたいです。1がチェックされると画像のように表示されるようにしたいです。
それと同じでサンプル2がクリックされたらサンプル1とサンプル3が表示されないようにといった感じです。。
分かる方、ご教示頂きたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```css
td {
    border: solid 1px;            
}
 
table {
    border-collapse:  collapse;     
}

.up_down_border {
  border-top-style: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.bottom_border {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.top_border {
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="sample1()">1のみ
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="sample2()">2のみ
      </div>
      <div>
          <input type="checkbox" onclick="sample3()">3のみ
      </div>

  <script>
    var flag = false;
    function sample1() {
      flag = true;
      sampleTable();
    }
    function sampleTable() {
      const table = document.createElement("table");
      const tableBody = {
          rows: [
            [{ value: "red" }, { value: "blue" }],
            [{ value: "メニュー", rowSpan: 8 }],
            [{ value: "サンプル1",className: "up_down_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル1", className: "top_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル2", className: "up_down_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル2", className: "top_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル3", className: "top_border" }],
            [{ value: "メニュー", rowSpan: 8 }],
            [{ value: "サンプル1", className: "up_down_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル1", className: "top_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル2", className: "up_down_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル2", className: "top_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border" }],
            [{ value: "サンプル3", className: "top_border" }],
          ]
        };
      for (var i = 0; i < tableBody.rows.length; i++) {
        const cols = tableBody.rows[i];
        const tr = document.createElement("tr");
        for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
          const col = cols[j];
          const td = document.createElement("td");
          td.innerHTML = col.value;
          if (col.className) {
            td.className = col.className;
          }
          if (col.rowSpan >= 0) {
            td.rowSpan = col.rowSpan;
          }
          tr.appendChild(td);
        }
        table.appendChild(tr);
      }
      document.querySelector("body").append(table);
    };
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、データ上でサンプル1〜3を区別する必要があるので、`tableBody` のサンプルの`className` に `group1` `group2` `group3` を追加します。

関数`sampleTable`は初めから実行するようにして、テーブルは最初は隠しておきます。`groupN` のクラスもデフォルトでは不可視にします。

チェックボックスの値が変化したら、テーブルに `groupNshown` のクラスを追加して、各グループのセルが見えるようにします。

チェックボックスが変更される度にテーブルを作り直す方法もありますが、一般的に見た目だけの変更はCSSクラス名の変更だけで行ったほうが実行コストが低いです。

あと本質的ではない点:

- チェックボックに付けるテキストは、`<label>`で囲みましょう。当たり判定が広くなりユーザが操作しやすくなります。
- チェックボックスの値が変更されたかどうかは `onchange` で判定します。`onclick` は意味的におかしいです。`onclick`ハンドラが呼ばれた後にブラウザがチェック状態を変更するとか、キーボード操作に対応しているように見えないとか。(実際はうまく動きますが)

```js
function updateTableClass(group, checked) {
  const table = document.querySelector('table');
  table.classList.toggle(group + 'shown', checked);
  table.hidden = table.classList.length == 0;
}

function sampleTable() {
  const table = document.createElement("table");
  table.hidden = true;
  const tableBody = {
    rows: [
      [{value: "red"}, {value: "blue"}],
      [{value: "メニュー", rowSpan: 8 }],
      [{value: "サンプル1", className: "up_down_border group1"}],
      [{value: "サンプル1", className: "top_border group1"}],
      [{value: "サンプル2", className: "up_down_border group2"}],
      [{value: "サンプル2", className: "top_border group2"}],
      [{value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border group3"}],
      [{value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border group3"}],
      [{value: "サンプル3", className: "top_border group3"}],
      [{value: "メニュー", rowSpan: 8}],
      [{value: "サンプル1", className: "up_down_border group1"}],
      [{value: "サンプル1", className: "top_border group1"}],
      [{value: "サンプル2", className: "up_down_border group2"}],
      [{value: "サンプル2", className: "top_border group2"}],
      [{value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border group3"}],
      [{value: "サンプル3", className: "up_down_border group3"}],
      [{value: "サンプル3", className: "top_border group3"}],
    ]
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < tableBody.rows.length; i++) {
    const cols = tableBody.rows[i];
    const tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      const col = cols[j];
      const td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = col.value;
      if (col.className) {
        td.className = col.className;
      }
      if (col.rowSpan >= 0) {
        td.rowSpan = col.rowSpan;
      }
      tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
  document.querySelector("body").append(table);
};

sampleTable();
```

```css
td {
  border: solid 1px;            
}
 
table {
  border-collapse:  collapse;     
}

.up_down_border {
  border-top-style: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.bottom_border {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.top_border {
  border-top: none;
}

.group1, .group2, .group3 {
  display: none;
}

.group1shown .group1,
.group2shown .group2,
.group3shown .group3 {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox"
    onchange="updateTableClass('group1', this.checked)">1のみ</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox"
    onchange="updateTableClass('group2', this.checked)">2のみ</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label><input type="checkbox"
    onchange="updateTableClass('group3', this.checked)">3のみ</label>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: 考え方まで解説してくださってありがとうございます。凄く助かりました。

Comment: 度々すいません、 table.hidden = table.classList.length == 0;ってどういう処理を行ってる箇所ですか？右辺を左辺に代入という考えしかなく、=　== とは、、、

Comment: @SA__091 さん、普通の代入文で、左辺が「table.hidden」右辺が「table.classList.length == 0」です。右辺は table.classList.length が 0 なら true、0 以外なら false になります。「groupNshown クラスが一つも付いてないなら true」ということです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。